# aframe-state component: remove function not called on removing entities produced by bind-for

Tags: aframe

I have such template :

```
<a-entity bind-for="for: item; in: creatures; key: id; updateInPlace: true">
  <template>
    <a-entity 
        bind-item__uw-id="item.id"
        bind-item__position="item.position"
        bind-item__rotation="item.rotation"
        bind-item__scale="item.scale"
        bind-item__uw-name="item.name"
        bind-item__gltf-model="item.url"
        animation-mixer></a-entity>
  </template>
</a-entity
```

After some event I want to remove all the entities from my scene. I'm trying to do it the following way:

```
export const cleanScene = () => {
    const camera = document.querySelector('a-camera')
    if (camera) {
        camera.parentNode.removeChild(camera);
        camera.destroy();
    }

    removeAframEntities('a-entity[bind-item__uw-id]');
    removeAframEntities('a-entity[bind-for]');
    removeAframEntities('a-entity');
    // document.querySelector('a-scene').systems.state.subscriptions = []; // - workaround
}

function removeAframEntities(selector) {
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(e => {
        e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        if (e.destroy) {
            e.destroy();
        }
    });
}
```

Then when I dispatch an event to the state, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of null
    at NewComponent.renderItemsInPlace (aframe-state-component.js:954)
    at NewComponent.<anonymous> (aframe-state-component.js:906)
    at NewComponent.onStateUpdate (aframe-state-component.js:1039)
    at NewSystem.<anonymous> (aframe-state-component.js:367)
```

This is because there is no entity to update, but there are still subscribers in the state. Apparently the `remove()` function wasn't called for the entities produced by the template loop (all the other subscribers are gone). Previously I was removing the entities by only calling `removeAframEntities('a-entity');`, I tried to explicitly remove the produced entities and the one with bind-for attribute, but it didn't solve my issue. What I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

Just checked the components code and it turned out that bind-for and bind-item components don't even have a `remove()` function. How they're supposed to be removed?

Comment: I’m in this same place. The bind for is adding but not removing entities

Comment: @Irwin, please check out this tread: https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/issues/278. The fix has been merged, but I haven't check if it was actually released.

Comment: Found my problem, @Nikita! The index of items has to be unique across sub-items in a list being displayed. Or the component system will keep redrawing the same sub-item.

Comment: glad you made it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was fixed here: https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/pull/279, I haven't checked if it was released though.